# Undefined function: .succes in $http.post (angular.js)

Tags: javascript, php, json, angularjs, post

I've been trying to make a search with Angular JS
but I get this weird error: TypeError: undefined is not a function 
and it is on the .success

Here is my code:

```
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script>
  var app = angular.module('app', []);

  app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope, $http){
      $scope.url = 'fetch.php';
      $scope.search = '';

      $scope.postLink = function(){

        $http.post($scope.url, { "data" : $scope.search}).succes(function(data, status){
          console.log(data);
        }).error(function(data, status) {
          $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
          $scope.status = status;   
        });
      }
  });

</script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="ctrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="search">
    <input type="submit" ng-click="postLink()">
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone tell my why it gives me an error on the .succes? Am I not allowed to call it there?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It’s spelled `success` …

Comment: wow... really... shame shame shame on me... thank you!

Comment: The `success` and `error` methods are removed from Angular as of version 1.6. See details in my answer below.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is spelled `success`.

`$http` is promised based, so you can also use:
`.then` for success,
`.catch` for fail and
`.finally` in both cases.

See:

- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http
- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: Thank you sir! Will look into that. The typo fixed my problem already. Can't believe I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 3):

There is a typo in the `succes` function name. Despite that, the `success` and `error` functions are now removed as of Angular 1.6 and should be replaced with the standard promise functions `.then()` / `.catch()`.

More details in this answer: [Why are angular $http success/error methods deprecated? Removed from v1.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329384/why-are-angular-http-success-error-methods-deprecated-removed-from-v1-6)

Answer (score 1):

It's `then` for $http promises.

At second, you have a typo, it should be `success`