# Why are AngularJS $http success/error methods deprecated? Removed from v1.6?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-http, angularjs-1.6

The AngularJS documentation has a Deprecation Notice for the `$http` `success` and `error` methods. Is there a specific reason this abstraction was removed from the library?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

The problem was that `.success` and `.error` methods are **not chainable** because they **ignore return values**. This caused problems for people familiar with **chaining** and encouraged poor code from people unfamiliar with **chaining**. Witness all the examples on StackOverflow that use the [deferred anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30750207/is-this-a-deferred-antipattern).

To quote one of the AngularJS team:

> IMO `.success` and `.error` were a bad bit of API design in the first place. This issue highlights a number of situations where developers get confused because they either expect `.success` and `.error` to work the same way as `.then` or vice versa.
>   In a perfect world I would rather just ditch these `$http` specific "promises". Instead we could encourage developers to use the standard `$q` promise API `.then` and `.catch`. There is very little benefit IMO in working with explicit parameters over working with the response object.
>
> [— AngularJS Issue #10508  `$http` `.success/.error` dissimilar from how `.then` works.](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/10508)

> ### Deprecation Notice (v1.5)
>
> The `$http` legacy promise methods `success` and `error` have been deprecated. Use the standard `then` method instead. If `$httpProvider.useLegacyPromiseExtensions` is set to `false` then these methods will throw `$http/legacy` error.
>
> [— AngularJS $http Service API Reference -- deprecation notice](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.10/docs/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice)

---

### UPDATE

The deprecated `.success` and `.error` methods have been removed from AngularJS 1.6.

> Due to [b54a39](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/b54a39e2029005e0572fbd2ac0e8f6a4e5d69014), `$http`'s deprecated custom callback methods - `.success()` and `.error()` - have been removed. You can use the standard `.then()`/`.catch()` promise methods instead, but note that the method signatures and return values are different.
>
> ```
> $http(...)
>   .then(function onSuccess(response) {
>     // Handle success
>     var data = response.data;
>     var status = response.status;
>     var statusText = response.statusText;
>     var headers = response.headers;
>     var config = response.config;
>     ...
>   }).catch(function onError(response) {
>     // Handle error
>     var data = response.data;
>     var status = response.status;
>     var statusText = response.statusText;
>     var headers = response.headers;
>     var config = response.config;
>     ...
>   });
> ```
>
> [— AngularJS Developer Guide - Migrating to v1.6 - http](https://code.angularjs.org/snapshot/docs/guide/migration#migrate1.5to1.6-ng-services-$http)

Answer (score 1):

The pattern that javascript it using related to promises is only with `.then(successCallback, errorCallback)`, so they are probably aiming to use js pattern.